# npm doesn't work with node v0.4.12 mac

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I don't know if I had npm and node installed on my mac before running the executable from the nodejs.org website, but at this time I am getting this error `Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.4.12` after running the install package.

I can't uninstall npm, the npm command is completely useless.

Please assist if you have insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the safest thing is to manage Node & NPM versions with [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version Manager). It installs (compiles) both Node & NPM for you, for each version you choose.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you have the new version of npm installed(v1.x.x) and an old version of node, e.g. v0.4.12, which are incompatible.

The best thing to do is **update node**, otherwise you could **download the old npm install bash script** from http://npmjs.org/install.sh and execute it (you might need to do it as sudo) The script will clean up all other versions of npm and install a version compatible with your node v0.4.12